# Django, ModelManager with a query based on model property

Tags: python, django

I have this models.py:

```
class PieceManager(models.Manager):
    def top_ten(self):
        # return self.get_queryset().order_by(total_likes)
        # How can I get the first n-items ordered by the property total_likes?


class Piece(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    museum = models.ForeignKey(Museum, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = PieceManager()

    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()


class Like(models.Model):

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    piece = models.ForeignKey(Piece, blank=True, null=True, related_name="likes")
```

How can I get the first -items ordered by total_likes property? What is the right way to do that? There is some better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple search would have shown, you can't sort by the result of a property or method.

However in this case you don't need to, since you can do it much better and more efficiently with aggregation:

```
from django.db.models import Count

self.annotate(likes_count=Count('like')).order_by('likes_count')
```